# Yii2 migration does not work on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, migration, yii2

Recently, I created Yii2 application(basic template) and successfully deployed it on Heroku. Then I wanted to set up database, so I added postgresql addon for heroku application and configured db config like this:

```
if (getenv("YII_ENV") == 'prod') {
    $url = parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
    $dsn = 'pgsql:host='.$url['host'].';port='.$url['port'].';dbname='.substr($url["path"], 1);
    $username = $url["user"];
    $password = $url["pass"];
} else {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2_quizie';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '1234';
}

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => $dsn,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

After that I've set two heroku config variables: `YII_ENV=prod` and `YII_DEBUG=false`.

Then I added simple migration and tried to run it using `heroku run bash` and then running `php yii migrate`

That's what I've received:

```
~ $ php yii migrate
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class yii\gii\Module does not exist'

in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:415

Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(415): ReflectionClass->__construct('yii\\gii\\Module')
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(358): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('yii\\gii\\Module')
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(151): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\gii\\Module', Array, Array)
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(340): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\gii\\Module', Array)
#4 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(354): yii\BaseYii::createObject('yii\\gii\\Module', Array)
#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(304): yii\base\Module->getModule('gii')
#6 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(267): yii\base\Application->bootstrap()
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(114): yii\base\Application->init()
#8 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Object.php(107): yii\console\Application->init()
#9 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(79): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#11 /app/yii(22): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#12 {main}
```

Anyone knows solution to this? On the local machine migration works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by running `composer install` in heroku shell. This is really weird, because heroku was suppose to automatically do it after upload of application.

Comment: If that's the case then it means that dependencies in your `composer.json` that are required to run these migrations in production are listed under `require-dev`,  and dev dependencies are not installed when deploying on Heroku (which makes sense; they're for local/CI development only). Move them to `require` :)

Comment: Yes, I already figured that out, but the thing is that exception wants Gii module to be installed. Gii module is only generator and it should definitely not be in production. I guess it's just Yii's screwup... Or something else...

Comment: Hence I'm not updating the answer, because I believe that configs are fine as they are, and it's responsibility of Yii creators to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to install `-dev` stuff in production, `YII_ENV` must be defined as `'prod'` both in the `web/index.php` and the `yii` script command itself.